# Match String with the Class property Names

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class with lets say 5 Properties

```
Int32 Property1;
Int32 Property2;
Int32 Property3;
Int32 Property4;
Int32 Property5;
```

Now I have to set the values of only 3 three of those properties dynamically. so far is OK but my issue is I get those three property Names as strings on runtime.
Lets say, something like this..

```
List<String> GetPropertiesListToBeSet()
{
   List<String> returnList = new List<String>();
   returnList.Add("Property1");
   returnList.Add("Property3");
   returnList.Add("Property4");
   retun returnList;
}
```

So Now,

```
 List<String> valuesList = GetPropertiesToBeSet();

 foreach (String valueToSet in valuesList)
 {
 // How Do I match these Strings with the property Names to set values
    Property1 = 1;
    Property3 = 2;
    Property4 = 3;
 }
```

Comment: Why can't you use a `Dictionary<string, Int32>` where the key is the property-name?

Comment: Or better yet an array or a Dictionary<int, int> where the index is the "property number" (e.g. `1` for `Property1`, etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this. Properties is your class

```
        Properties p = new Properties();
        Type tClass = p.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] pClass = tClass.GetProperties();

        int value = 0; // or whatever value you want to set
        foreach (var property in pClass)
        {
            property.SetValue(p, value++, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's say that the name of the class which contains them is `Properties`. You can use the [`GetProperty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy0d4103(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get a [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and then the [`SetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
Type t = p.GetType(); //or use typeof(Properties)

int value = 1;
foreach (String valueToSet in valuesList) {
   var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance; //because they're private properties
   t.GetProperty(valueToSet, bindingFlags).SetValue(p, value++); //where p is the instance of your object
}
```